# Improve validation time java

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, validation

I'd like to improve my program execution time. The program import CSV data, and validate it, line by line.

After several tests, I noticed that 90% of the loop's time was spend in this line :

```
HashSet<ConstraintViolation<EntryDTO>> l = ValidationTools.validate(this.validator, entryDTO);
```

entryDTO contains all the fields of my current line, and this.validator contains the rules the fields must follow.
So I checked (in the ValidationTools class) how this method was implemented :

```
public static <T> HashSet<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate(Validator validator, T resource, Class<?>... groups) {
        return (HashSet<ConstraintViolation<T>>) validator.validate(resource, groups);
    }
```

Which directly refers to the javax.validation.Validator, so I can not improve anything on it... is there anything I can do better to improve the execution time ?

Last but not least, I noticed that this method was taking more and more time at every iteration of my loop... making me think about a problem with the garbage collector.

Thanks if you have any lead :)

Comment: The problem is in the code you haven't provided (and claim you can't). Hardly much to start with. At least you can use VisualVM to pinpoint the method where the time leaks.

Comment: `javax.validation.Validator` is an interface. What kind of validator are you using?

Comment: And what does your `validator.validate()` method? It's this method which take time I guess!

Comment: @AlexR : I'm using this validator :  `<!-- Constraint validator -->
 <bean id="validator" name="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />`

Comment: So, you should continue your discovery by monitoring of performance of `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` and its parts although this is the Spring code. When you have information you can probably decide how to improve the performance by either using different input or configuration of the validator (if available) or even by using other validator.

Comment: According to [this link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/114639-performance-issues-using-localvalidatorfactorybean), '<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">' Create n validators for n items, which can explain why it takes more and more time...